# how to setup blockchain url for bitcoin operations? what will be the base url for blockchain operations url?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3, blockchain

My code snippet:

```
    class Blockchain{
        protected $guid; // Blockchain wallet identifier (Wallet ID)
        protected $api_code; // API code, required for creating wallets
        protected $main_password; // Main Blockchain Wallet password
        protected $second_password; // Second Blockchain Wallet password if double encryption is enabled
        protected $port = 3000; // Blockchain Wallet service port
        protected $base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1'; // Base url to connect to the Blockchain Wallet service

        public function __construct($config)
        {
            // Set config values
            $this->guid = $config['guid'];
            $this->main_password = $config['main_password'];
            // Optional ones
            $this->api_code = ( isset($config['api_code']) ) ? $config['api_code'] : NULL;
            $this->second_password = ( isset($config['second_password']) ) ? $config['second_password'] : NULL;
            $this->base_url = ( isset($config['base_url']) ) ? $config['base_url'] : $this->base_url;
            $this->port = ( isset($config['port']) ) ? $config['port'] : $this->port;

            log_message('info', 'Blockchain Class Initialized');

            // Check if the Blockchain Wallet service is running
            if ($this->execute($this->base_url.':'.$this->port) === NULL) {
                show_error('Blockchain: Unable to connect to Blockchain Wallet service on: '.$this->base_url.':'.$this->port.'');
                log_message('error', "Blockchain: Unable to connect to Blockchain Wallet service.");
            }
        }

        public function wallet_balance()
        {
            // Get the base url
            $url=$this->base_url;

            // Add the port
            $url.=':'.$this->port.'/';

            // Add the api url
            $url.='merchant/'.$this->guid.'/balance';

            // Add options
            // password
            $url.='?password='.$this->main_password;

            // Execute
            return $this->execute($url);
        }

    public function execute($url)
    {
        // Get CURL resource
        $curl = curl_init();
        // Set options
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            // CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
        ));

        // Send the request & save response
        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        // Close request to clear up some resources
        curl_close($curl);

        log_message('debug', 'Blockchain: URL executed '.$url);

        // Return the decoded response as an associative array
        return json_decode($response, TRUE);
    }
}
```

what will be the base_url..

i am not understanding the base url part..

will it local or "https://api.blockchain.info" (like this)

what exactly i have to mention in following statement of above code-snippet:

```
protected $base_url = '???????????';
```

from which link i will get correct response??

what is exact procedure to connect with blockchain??

please clarify me this..

Comment: have you got the answer, please post here if got......thanks

Comment: @JayantBramhankar Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the [Codeigniter-blockchain](https://github.com/mehdibo/Codeigniter-blockchain) library.

The `base_url` is the URL that points to the Blockchain Wallet Service you installed, a full guide to install the service can be found [here](https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3#installation).

You need to have `nodejs` and `npm` installed.

To install the Blockchain Wallet Service, run this command:

```
npm install -g blockchain-wallet-service
```

Now after the installation, you can start it with this command:

```
blockchain-wallet-service start --port 3000
```

`3000` is the port number, you can change it if you would like to.

Now back to the library:

```
protected $base_url = '???????????';
```

This should be set to the URL where the Blockchain Wallet Service is installed, in this case `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, which is already set by default.

```
protected $port = 3000;
```

This is the port number where Blockchain Wallet Service is running, this should be the same port you used while starting the service.

Comment: You save my day Thanks